# How to split a string to sequences of odd numbers?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to find a way to split a number to list of odd number sequences:

```
num = "57483795478973"

for digit in num:
    if int(digit)%2==0:
        list_a = str.split(num,digit)

print (list_a)
```

but the result I'm getting is

```
['574', '379547', '973']
```

which includes the even numbers, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you want the output `['57', '3795', '7', '973']`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('[02468]', '57483795478973')
['57', '', '3795', '7', '973']
```

The first argument, in this case, is effectively a list of delimiters - which are even numbers in your case. If you want to skip empty results:

```
>>>[r for r in re.split('[02468]', '57483795478973') if r]
['57', '3795', '7', '973']
```

---

And here is a way to calculate it by hand, using a [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield):

```
def splitToOddSeqs(numbers):
    seq = ""
    for n in numbers:
        if n not in "02468":
            seq += n      # as long as we have odd numbers, we accumulate
        else:
            if seq:
                yield seq # we've found an even number - return one sequence
                seq = ""

    if seq:
        yield seq         # return last one (when input ends with odd digit)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list(splitToOddSeqs('57483795478973'))
['57', '3795', '7', '973']
```

Comment: I liked this answer better when it was just `re.split()`. The generator is, first of all, a completely different approach (so technically should probably be its own separate answer); and secondly, it's both more verbose and (I think) harder to understand for Python beginners.

Comment: @JohnY I imagined that regexps are a thing that's hard for beginners, and that's why I added the second version. I agree with you, that a generator is also not an easy concept, but I think showing how the partial results are being calculated has some educational value. Perhaps I'll add some comments.

Comment: I'm totally with you that regular expressions can also be hard for beginners. But in this particular case, the only thing they need to grasp is that `[02468]` is a set of characters, and that `re.split()` will split on anything in the set. So it's actually a cross between the built-in string methods `split()` and `strip()` (with the latter's argument semantics).

Comment: thank you ! this solved my problem and helped me complete the rest of my exercise.... (finding what the longest sequence is, and at which index of the string it starts). thanks again [:

Answer (score 1):

You're calculating `list_a` every time through the loop.  The final time through the loop ('8') gives the result that you see.  What you want is to split on '0', '2', '4' and '6' as well as '8'.

Answer (score 1):

Alongside the other good answers , you can use `itertools.groupby` (good if you are consider about performance ):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l=[list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(num,lambda x : int(x)%2==0)]
>>> [''.join(i) for i in l if int(i[0])%2!=0]
['57', '3795', '7', '973']
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the result you want is:

```
['57', '3795', '7', '973']
```

But every iteration through the loop, you replace `list_a` with the most recent `str.split(num, digit)`.  Since `8` is the last even digit in `num`, the final value of `list_a` is `str.split(num, '8')` - a string that's only split on 8's.

Passing your output through `split` over and over again won't work either, because after the first `split`, you're working with a list of strings instead of a single string.

I'm surprised Python doesn't provide a library function that splits on any of a set of characters.  Looks like you'll need to write it yourself.

Also, your code does extra work by looping over the digits in `num` instead of just looping over all the even digits once.  If `num` is very long, you'll end up splitting on the same digit over and over, wasting effort.

I wrote a less Pythonic, more C-like answer, but I like the answers using regex, `itertools`, and generators better.

Comment: Re: surprise that there's no library function for this: `re.split()` **is** the library function for this. As I commented on BartoszKP's answer, you don't have to learn much in the way of regular expressions to use `re.split()` in this manner.